# How to make div not larger than its contents - is it because display: flex?

Tags: html, css, vue-material

I've read many questions in stackoverflow about this issue, but I'm not able to make it work in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/bitfhacker/8nvyawq1/19/

```css
.md-layout-item {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  min-height: 140px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/theme/default.css">

    <div class="md-layout">
      <div class="md-layout-item md-size-5">
        <div style="white-space: nowrap; width: auto;">Long text</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="md-layout-item">
        Other long text
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried display: inline-block, width: auto, ... but I can't make it work. Whats's the problem?

Comment: `md-size-5` sets the width to 5% of the width of the row. With a cell that small what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
display: inline-flex;
```

Like so:

```
.md-layout-item {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  min-height: 140px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```